# Django, Default file icon is missing after download of file

Tags: django, save

I have written code for downloading a file through an API. It works fine as I can see. The file size is the same. But the file has no longer a default file icon. I am pretty new at this and maybe I am doing something wrong. I am reading the file as I would for a standard textfile and saving it in the same way with the binary option. So how can the files be same size and still something seems to be missing in the downloaded file? Is there a better way to download files?
This is the code on the server:

```py
file_location = 'static/File.pkg'
try:    
     with open(file_location, 'rb') as f:
        filex_data = f.read()
     response = HttpResponse(filex_data, content_type='application/octet-stream')
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="File.pkg"'
return response
```

This is the code on my local computer:

```py
url = 'http://myServer/waprfile/'
x = requests.get(url, data=data,  headers=headers)
f = open("TheNewFile.pgk", "ab")
f.write(x.content)
f.close()
```

Comment: Does this happen with all browsers?

Comment: I don't use a browser. It is a python application running locasl. I download from an API. As you see in the code, I am sending a request to the server url only. Then the Django application handles the rest.